# @layout/activity_main does not contain a declaration with id tvDescription

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am getting the following error. during I am creating the

```
tvDescription = findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
```

[Error]:--> `@layout/activity_main` does not contain a declaration with id tvDescription

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListFrag.ItemSelected {

    TextView tvDescription;
    ArrayList<String> description;
    @Override`enter code here`
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout.activity_main);

        tvDescription = findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);

        description = new ArrayList<>();
        description.add("Description for item 1");
        description.add("Description for item 2");
        description.add("Description for item 3");
        description.add("Description for item 4");
        description.add("Description for item 5");

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(int index) {
        tvDescription.setText(description.get(index));
    }
```

---

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="@string/description"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 8):

Try to follow below steps:

1. Clean and Rebuild Project.
2. If issue is still there, Goto File ->Invaliadte Caches..

Update: I missed the bug
I think @vijay-jv is right on pointing out exact mistake.
use R.layout.activity_main instead of layout.activity_main

Comment: I used it already but it still showing error

Comment: rebuilding again work ed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try changing

```
setContentView(layout.activity_main);
```

To

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: I had also tried but still. I am getting error

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Try creating another project might work.

Comment: I'll also try.  I had created a new project minimum of 2 times but still, it's showing an error. can I access the id of the fragment inside MainActivity

Comment: @QADRISALMAN Are you finding the ID of a fragment in your  activity? (I'd of a fragment can't be accessed in activities) use menu XML file or Fragment Transaction to get support of Fragment manager and this time you should directly use navigation components (nav graph) they are reliable and easy to use. https://medium.com/@muhamed.riyas/navigation-component-the-complete-guide-c51c9911684

Answer (score 1):

I am learning Android these days, and I also face the same problem.
And I just found that, This code mean that you have not declare this id in the **activity.xml**

Maybe you have declared this id in **another activity.xml**.
Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
tools:context =".Mainactivity"
```

from the xml file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

R.layout.activity_main remove and Import again.. 100% Solved This Issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my situation the R.layout.activity_main was utilized but the error persists. My solution was to go to "File" menu on your IDE and click on the "Sync Project with Grade Files" as seen below:

[image]